# Scipy gmean with missing values

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, missing-data, geometric-mean

I was not sure how to deal with a two dimensional array [stock returns] that has some missing values.

I want to get geometric mean for each row [ average return for each month]. I got missing values for geometric mean for those months that I have missing values.

One way is to filling the missing values with something like 1 or mean but I don't want to mess with the mean.

Any advice how to calculate the gmean for each date just based on the not-missing values?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go with `numpy.nanmean()`

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html

Comment: Thanks!
Is there similar function for geometric mean or I have to take log and then use nanmean?

Comment: You can go with scipy `scipy.stats.mstats.gmean()`

Comment: As I mentioned above, `scipy.stats.mstats.gmean()` returns NaN if there is any missing value

Comment: oh forgot about that, in that case just implement it yourself, its very little code anyways